# UITableViewCell with UIImageView in a few of them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a customized `UITableViewCell` and I've added a `UIImageView` to it. The thing is, there are times when I want to remove the `UIImageView` as the data I receive from the server does not have an image associated with it. How do I make the cell layout change such that the other elements move up. Should I set the UIImageView's frame to zero? Using a placeholder image is **not** a solution.

Here's what my problem looks like:

[image: Tableview SS]

The row with index 0 does not have an image but there is a space in between the top and the bottom label. Is there a way I can do this using Auto Layout?

Comment: also u need to change the height for cell in "heightForRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: You can design two custom cells, one for data with image and other for without image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually caused by `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you have to return the proper value in this method, something like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   YourCustomObject *object = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   if(object.hasImage) {
      return heightForCellWithImageInside;
   }
   else {
     return heightForCellWithoutImageInside;
   }
}
```

Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just hide the `UIImageView` if there is no image for it.

Comment: And pin other elements to top and bottom?

Comment: Yes, make all the layout to be positioned depending on the top of the cell. Or you can create a different cell for the case when you don't have an UIImageView, I think is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically change the height of cell.If there is an image,then increase cell height otherwise not.Also set the imageView whenever u get image from server otherwise no need to set imageView.like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ImageCellItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if(imageFromserver) 
{   
  //Set your imageView here 
}
else
{
// Do nothing
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when ever there is no image coming from server hide or remove your image view and assign the frame of image view to your bottom label.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}
if(yourimage==nil)
{
  bottomlabel.frame=imageview.frame; // you can do something like this, as per your need.this is just example
}
return cell;
```